# Validation Dates using Javascript & ASP.Net

Tags: javascript

I have an ASP.Net form in which users can choose the date from Calendar Extender control, I have 2 fields for the date (FromDate & ToDate).

I want to validate the following using javascript:

- FromDate should be always less than ToDate
- FromDate & ToDate should not be less than today's date.

If both conditions are true, I would like then to call a method from the codebehind which will calculate the total number of days within the selected period excluding the weekends and display it to the user (this method works fine).

In the code below I tried __doPostBack to fire the codebehind method when the two previously mentioned conditions are met. It fires the codebehind method but then javascript variables  becomes incorrect (compareDate variable is always increment on each function call & postback) and thus all the result becomes incorrect.

**Below is the current method I use to validate the date using Javascript, it's fired from OnClientDateSelectionChanged event from both textboxes's calendar extender controls **

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var fromDate = new Date();
        var toDate = new Date();

        function checkDate(sender, args) {

            if (sender.get_id() == 'CalendarExtenderFrom') {
                fromDate = sender._selectedDate;
            }
            else if (sender.get_id() == 'CalendarExtenderTo') {
                toDate = sender._selectedDate;
            }

            // Check if selected date is less than today's date
            var todayDate = new Date();
            var year = todayDate.getFullYear();
            var month = todayDate.getMonth();
            var day = todayDate.getDate();
            var dateOnly = new Date(year, month, day);

            if (sender._selectedDate < dateOnly) {
               alert("You cannot select a day earlier than today!");
               sender._textbox.set_Value("");
               return;
            }

            // Check if FromDate > ToDate
            if (document.getElementById('TextBoxDateOfLeave').value != "" && document.getElementById('TextBoxDateOfReturn').value != "") {

                var compareDate = new Date(fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), (fromDate.getDate()) + 1, 00, 00, 00, 00);

                if (toDate < compareDate) {

                   alert("(Return Date) should be greater than (Travel Date)");
                   sender._textbox.set_Value("");
                   return;
                }

            }

            // If both conditions are met
            window.__doPostBack('__Page', '');
        }

    </script>
```

**ASP.Net Controls:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateOfLeave" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ontextchanged="CalculateLeaveDays"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderFrom" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBoxDateOfLeave" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDateOfReturn" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ontextchanged="CalculateLeaveDays"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderTo" runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBoxDateOfReturn" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate" />
```

---

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you looking for something like this? I added a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww2WT/) here. I used the jquery ui date picker, but you can use any datepicker of your choice, provided the values are in 'yyyy/mm/dd' or 'mm/dd/yyyy' I think